# Ruby metaprog + redefining methods on include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

It's been a while since I've done any Ruby metaprogramming, but I'm trying to create a little DSL and wondering if it's even possible to do what I'm envisioning.  I have some policy classes like this:

```rb
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def index?
    user.admin?
  end
end
```

I want to add the ability to mark certain methods as role based, with a DSL like this:

```rb
  # ...
  auth :index?, roles: ['admin:all', 'admin:users:view']
```

On the backend, it would check the User to see if they have the roles assigned, and then call the original method.

I started playing with Concerns, but because the `auth` method needs defined before it's called and the `index?` method within the policy is defined after the include, I can't seem to get it to honor the new `index?` method that can super up to the old.  Here's kinda what I was testing:

```rb
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  include RoleBasedAuth
  
  auth :index?, roles: ['admin:all', 'admin:users:view']

  def index?
    user.admin?
  end
end

module RoleBasedAuth
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def auth(method_name, roles:)
      define_method method_name do
        roles.any? { |role| user.roles.include?(role) } && super
      end
    end
  end
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Should be commenting instead of answering, but as a newbie I have not enough reputation. Anyway, have you tried to move your include below the `index?` method definition?

Comment: Yep, but if you do that, the auth method is not yet available when loading the class so you get a NoMethodError on that